# Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ssh, capistrano

**Local Computer Username: Christopher**

**Ubuntu Server Username: my_app_name**

I have followed the Digital Ocean documentation to set up an Ubuntu 16.04 server with Ruby on Rails and is my first time doing so, though when I get to `cap production deploy:initial` the console returns `Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user Christopher@12.23.34.45` even though I am able to ssh without a problem into my root and user accounts.

I followed these instructions:

**How to connect your droplet with Digital Ocean**
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-connect-to-your-droplet-with-ssh

**Initial Server Setup with Ubuntu 16.04**
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04

I generated an ssh public/private key pair on my local computer using:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I added the public key from my local computer to the servers `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. I was then able to ssh into my root and user accounts.

I then followed these instructions:

**Deploying a Rails App on Ubuntu 14.04 with Capistrano, Nginx, and Puma**
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma

I generated another ssh key, this time on the server and added the public key to my github's deploy keys list. I was then able to successfully clone my repo through ssh.

I run the following commands:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -p your_port_num deploy@your_server_ip 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'

cap production deploy:initial
```

And get back:

```
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user Christopher@12.23.34.45
```

I would really appreciate any help as this is my very first time deploying to an Ubuntu server and I would really like to learn what it is I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Did you add your key to the Agent?

What do you see when you run:

```
$ ssh-add -l
```

If you get 'The agent has no identities.', then add your key with:

```
$ ssh-add id_rsa_key_name
```

Comment: ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: @Ctpelnar1988 can you mark the answer please? The advice in this response was the solution to my own problem.

Comment: Every time I need to add pem key. Is there any way to add permanently ?

Comment: It works. Thank you! But why is this happened since I didn't change anything? It was suddenly happened. Just curious.

Answer (score 10):

First of all you need to ssh to your server and run

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

and then

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and now change

```
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
#
```

to

```
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa) }
#
```

I just removed `pub` from `id_rsa.pub`.

And then run

```
cap production deploy:initial
```

It should work now. Same changes fixed the issues for my app https://www.wiki11.com.

Answer (score 4):

You have :
    `set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }`

Change it to:
    `set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa) }`

Keys should have private key location only. Also, enable ssh-agent on local machine using `ssh-add`. Add `ForwardAgent yes` in `~/.ssh/config` for your Host.

Answer (score 1):

I had some [weird problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73713317/capistrano-3-asks-for-ssh-users-password-since-do-release-upgrade-was-done-on) as long as I did not use bundler. So using capistrano like so then worked again for me:

```
# good
bundle exec cap production deploy
```

Instead of just:

```
# no good
cap production deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line to your config/deploy.rb

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```

Refer [this post.](http://blog.blenderbox.com/2013/02/20/ssh-agent-forwarding-with-github/)

Comment: Thanks but I already had it. `set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }`