# Capistrano 3 asks for SSH user's password since `do-release-upgrade` was done on Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ssh, capistrano

I have a rails app that I could so far successfully deploy to my Ubuntu server using capistrano 3.

Last night I did a successful server update using `do-release-upgrade`:

```
Linux my-server 5.15.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 07:51:15 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I can still `ssh` into the server using my `id_rsa` key from my Mac Terminal:

```
ssh user@my-server.example.com
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-47-generic x86_64)
```

However Capistrano now asks for the password instead of asking me for the passkey of my `id_rsa` certificate:

```
cap production deploy
user@my-server.example.com's password:
```

I tried to run `ssh-copy-id` too to make sure the certificate is re-uploaded:

```
ssh-copy-id user@my-server.example.com     
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: WARNING: All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system.
                (if you think this is a mistake, you may want to use -f option)
```

It's all quite weird since just yesterday I did do several deployments:

```
ls -lia rails/releases/ | grep 20220913 | wc -l
9
```

I did not enable passwords for the SSH access at all so I am wondering how to re-enable the SSH communication with my sever.

#### Update

The issue might be related to "SSH agent forwarding". I did use `capistrano-ssh-doctor` and it told me that:

> ### SSH agent forwarding report
>
> 1. [success] `repo_url` setting ok
> 2. [success] ssh private key file exists
> 3. [success] `ssh-agent` process seems to be running locally
> 4. [success] `ssh-agent` process recognized by `ssh-add` command
> 5. [success] ssh private keys added to `ssh-agent`
> 6. [success] application repository accessible from local machine
> 7. [success] all hosts using passwordless login
> 8. [success] `forward_agent` ok for all hosts
> 9. [success] ssh agent successfully forwarded to remote hosts
> 10. [error] It seems Capistrano cannot access application git repository from these hosts: my-server.example.com
>     Actions:
>
> - make sure all the previous checks pass. That should make this one work too.
>
> ---
>
> It seems SSH agent forwarding is not set up correctly. Follow the
> suggested steps described in error messages. Errors (if more than one)
> are ordered by importance, so always start with the first one.

So I logged in on the server and I was able to successfully clone the repository.

There is some information in [this post](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-ssh-doctor/issues/7#issuecomment-222394937):

> I'd still like to find out why I can't use the `git@github.com:{github-organization}/{private-repo}.git` format for `:repo_url`, with keys, when all of the SSH forwarding report's requirements seem to be met. If you need further info from me just let me know - and thanks again for any help!

So it seems that the `:repo_url` needs to be changed. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure out that now for some reason the following command does no longer work:

```
cap staging deploy
```

Instead I need to use bundler

```
bundle exec cap staging deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. This fixed it for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409105/ubuntu-22-04-ssh-the-rsa-key-isnt-working-since-upgrading-from-20-04

Add this to the end of /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```